# Evaluated expression const variable scope in Safari

Tags: javascript, exception, scope, safari, eval

Would appreciate to know why this expression:

```
eval("const a = function () {}; function b() {  a(); }; b();")
```

throws an error when run in Safari 10.1.2:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: a

Comment: Because Safari is the new Internet Explorer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that using `const` (or `let`) put this variable into some internal `eval`'s scope, whereas functions called inside `eval` are using:

1. global scope if they were defined by `function X(){}`;
2. internal scope if they were defined as `const X = function(){}`.

For example, using `const`:

```
> eval('const a = function(){ return 42; }; a();')
42
> a
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: a
```

Using `var`:

```
> eval('var a = function(){ return 42; }; a();')
42
> a
function (){ return 42; }
```

---

In support of this theory:

```
> eval('const a=function(){return 42;}; const b=function(){return a();}; b();')
42
> a
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: a
> b
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: b
```

So, it works if we'll define both function the same way.

Now, let's do define function `a` in global scope, without using `eval`:

```
> a = function(){ return 23;}
```

And let's run `eval` code from your question (adding `return`s to both functions):

```
> eval("const a = function(){return 42;}; function b(){return a();}; b();")
23
```

As you can see, function `b` is using `a` from global scope.

Comment: Great! For some reason Safari doesn't create closure for function `b` with the local variables defined during `eval()`, that's different for Chrome. I am not sure what's the correct behavior, bay damn you Safari for wasting my time!